# I do not understand type casting

Tags: c++

I'm a complete newb at programming and have had no experience of programming before. I bought a book called *C++ Programming for the Absolute Beginner* by Mark Lee (not advertising or anything) and at the end of Lesson 2 (which shows of variables and forgets to explain casting) they give you this game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::string;
    string name;
    cout << "Welcome to the weapon store, noble knight."
         << " Come to equip the army again?\n"
         << "What is your name? ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Well then, Sir " << name.c_str()
         << ", let's get shopping\n";
    double gold = 50.0;
    int silver = 8;
    const double SILVERPERGOLD = 6.7;
    const double BROADSWORDCOST = 3.6;
    unsigned short broadswords;
    cout << "You have " << gold << " gold pieces and "
         << silver << " silver." << "\nThat is equal to ";
    gold += silver / SILVERPERGOLD;
    cout << gold << " gold.\n";
    cout << "How many broadswords would you like to buy?"
         << " (3.6) gold each ";
    cin >> broadswords;
    gold = gold - broadswords * BROADSWORDCOST;
    cout << "\nThank you. You have " << gold << " left.\n";
    silver = (int)((gold - (int)gold)) * SILVERPERGOLD;
    gold = (double)((int)(gold));
    cout << "That is equal to " << gold << " gold and "
         << silver << " silver. \n"
         << "Thank you for shopping at the Weapon Store. "
          << "Have a nice day, Sir " << name.c_str() << ".\n";
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

I have some questions with this code:

1. What does the += operator mean in:

   `gold += silver / SILVERPERGOLD;`
2. What does the following mean? I am clueless in what type casting is.

   `silver = (int)((gold - (int)gold)) * SILVERPERGOLD;
   gold = (double)((int)(gold));`

Please do not hate me for being a noob and please explain it in a way a newb would understand. Thanks!

Comment: Silver is cast to a double so that it equals 8.0

Comment: "`cout << name.c_str()`" and "`(int)gold`"? Throw this book away and [get a real one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sorry mate but no.

Comment: @SirWilliamofOrange this book is already teaching you bad habits, such as C style casts. You should take the advice.

Comment: As [STL says](http://nuwen.net/gcc.html), bad programmers are your main enemy. The write books and blogs and post on the internet, and they outnumber good programmers by a large margin.

Comment: @OMGtechy Well I already bought the book. Can't buy another one. So any advice on what is the correct way of doing that program?

Comment: @OMGtechy What I did is instead of using "using std::cout" in main() I just use: using namespace std; after #include. I took out c_str(). I still don't understand C Casting because I don't understand what it means in this program.

Comment: Well I know this sucks, but if you want to learn C++ you should not use this book.

Comment: @SirWilliamofOrange: I have to second the book issue. Go exchange the book for something on the [beginner's C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) curated by members of the C++ community on Stack Overflow. It will be far less frustrating in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gold += silver / SILVERPERGOLD
```

`+=` means "increment the variable on the left side of `+=` by the amount on the right side".

```
silver = (int)((gold - (int)gold)) * SILVERPERGOLD; 
gold = (double)((int)(gold));
```

This is a really, really, really wrong way to do a floating point remainder calculation.

Type castiing is another name for explicit type conversion.

```
(double)x
```

means "take the value of `x` and return 'the same' value but of type `double`". If `x` is 7, the result will be 7.0. It is a long obsolete way to do a type cast in C++. Google "c style casts" for more info.

Correspondingly,

```
(int)x
```

means "take x and return 'the same' value as `int`". If x is 7.83, the result is 7 (i.e. the fractional part is dropped).

So `((gold - (int)gold))` would mean "subtract the whole part from `gold`, leaving the fractional part". Then the author multiplies the result by the gold-to-silver conversion rate, and rounds it down to a whole number. This presumably gives us the amount of change in silver pieces. Finally, with `gold = (double)((int)(gold))` the author rounds the amount of gold down to a whole number. The fractional part is already converted to silver, so the two numbers, `gold` and `silver`, together comprise the sum of money you have.

The entire operation tries to fit a whole number of gold pieces into the price, and make up the rest with silver. Never do it this way.

Comment: "take the value of x and treat it as having type double". - no, it means to convert the value of `x` to type `double`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb this is correct but doesn't explain much. "Cast" and "convert" are synonymous, explaining one with the other doesn't go very far.

Comment: @nm They aren't synonymous. *Cast* means an explicit conversion; there are also non-cast conversions (aka. implicit conversions).   Although I take your point that saying "A cast converts the value" is actually not saying much. I'll rephrase: I think "treats the value as" is not a good description; it's reminiscent of what happens when you cast `int *` to `char *`, that is normally described as "treating the int as a series of characters". When converting `double` to `int` for example, the value may change; you lose information. It produces a new value - not a view of the old value.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have changed the wording somewhat.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks a lot I've researched a little bit and have erased some bad habits that the author shows me. Thanks!